# How do I pass ‘generic’ ngrx actions as parameter?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I want to write a CRUD service for some of my entities, but want to write the logic in an abstract class. For simplicity sake, these are my action groups, note that all code is stripped down for this question:

```
export const GroupsActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Groups',
  events: {
    'Load Groups': emptyProps(),
    'Add Group': props<{ group: GroupModel }>(),
    'Update Group': props<{ group: GroupModel }>(),
    'Remove Group': props<{ id: number }>(),
  },
});
export const ShapeActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Shapes',
  events: {
    'Load Shapes': emptyProps(),
    'Add Shape': props<{ shape: ShapeModel }>(),
    'Update Shape': props<{ shape: ShapeModel }>(),
    'Remove Shape': props<{ id: number }>(),
  },
});
export const ColorActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Colors',
  events: {
    'Load Colors': emptyProps(),
    'Add Color': props<{ color: ColorModel }>(),
    'Update Color': props<{ color: ColorModel }>(),
    'Remove Color': props<{ id: number }>(),
  },
});
```

Now I have an abstract `CRUDService<T>` that needs to take in the different actions, like so (pseudo):

```
@Component({ template: '' })
export abstract class CRUDService<T> {
  constructor(
    private addAction ???,
    private updateAction ???,
    private deleteAction ???
  ) {}
  //...
}
```

So that I can do some generic stuff in this class like:

```
saveEntry = (entity: T) => {
  //... Validation, create updatedEntity with updated stats
  // Create a new object if the id === 0, Update it otherwise
    entity.id === 0
      ? this.store.dispatch(this.addAction(updatedEntity))
      : this.store.dispatch(this.updateAction(updatedEntity));
}

deleteEntry = (entity: T) => this.store.dispatch(this.deleteAction(entity.id));
```

In the explicit service, I would then like to pass the actions, like so (pseudo):

```
export class CRUDGroupsComponent extends CRUDService<GroupModel> {
  private readonly store = inject(Store);
  private readonly fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  constructor() {
    super(
      GroupsActions.addGroup,
      GroupsActions.updateGroup,
      GroupsActions.removeGroup);
  }
}
```

And the same thing goes for the ‘Shapes’ and the ‘Colors’. I hope this is clear enough of what I’m trying to achieve. If some things are unclear, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic action interface

```
export interface ICRUDAction<T> {
  type: string;
  payload: T;
}
```

Modify the constructor of your abstract CRUDService to accept generic actions as parameters:

```
export abstract class CRUDService<T> {
  constructor(
    private readonly addAction: ICRUDAction<T>,
    private readonly updateAction: ICRUDAction<T>,
    private readonly deleteAction: ICRUDAction<T>
  ) {}

  // ...
}
```

In each explicit service, inject the store and perform the injection of the actions using interface projection:

```
export class CRUDGroupsComponent extends CRUDService<GroupModel> {
  private readonly store = inject(Store);
  private readonly fb = inject(FormBuilder);

  constructor() {
    super(
      GroupsActions.addGroup as ICRUDAction<GroupModel>,
      GroupsActions.updateGroup as ICRUDAction<GroupModel>,
      GroupsActions.removeGroup as ICRUDAction<number>
    );
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by introducing abstract methods to my base class:

**CRUDService**

```
abstract addItemAction: (item: T) => void;
abstract updateItemAction: (item: T) => void;
abstract removeItemAction: (id: number) => void;
```

And then overriding them in the child classes with concrete implementations using the dispatch method from the store:

**CRUDGroupsComponent**

```
override readonly addItemAction = (group: GroupModel) =>
  this.store.dispatch(GroupsActions.addGroup({ group }));
override readonly updateItemAction = (group: GroupModel) =>
  this.store.dispatch(GroupsActions.updateGroup({ group }));
override readonly removeItemAction = (id: number) =>
  this.store.dispatch(GroupsActions.removeGroup({ id }));
```

In my case I use the ngrx store, but one may also use something else like a simple service. This way, the concrete implementation details of the actions stay out of the base class.